# How to use epsilon-delta to prove the multivariable limit when x and y don’t tend to 0

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I’ve been trying to understand how to prove this multi-variable limit using a delta-epsilon proof, but find that I am unable to when both $x$ and $y$ tend to numbers that are not $0$. In this case specifically, both $x$ and $y$ tend to $3$.

> **Question:** $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(3,3)}\dfrac{(x-y)^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

If anyone is able to provide some guidance or assistance, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You can simply plug in $(x,y)=(3,3)$ by continuity

Comment: however to do an epsilon delta proof you could just define new variables $(v,w) = (x-3,y-3)$